# Swift: Add all buttons to an array

Tags: arrays, swift, button

I'm a novice at Swift programming.

I've created an app with multiple identical buttons. I created one button with an action and then copied this button multiple times so that it uses the same action.

Is there an easy way to add all these buttons (there are around 100) to an array, so that I can change for example the button image for all of them in one go?

Since there are so many buttons, I'd like to avoid having to add them all, one-by-one, to an Outlet collection.

As mentioned I'm a novice, so the simpler the better.

***Edit***
All the instances of the button has the tag '1' if that's any help and was created via the main storyboard.

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: That's a lot of buttons. Perhaps you should group them in a table, or some other UI to organize and manage them

Comment: It depends on your UI, let us know your User Interface

Comment: Please show the screenshot of that view which contains buttons. It will help to suggest the best way.

Comment: I created one via the storyboard (not programmatically), and then copied it multiple times.

Comment: Thats not the correct way. If you will show the UI so I can see if collection or table can be use here or some other way. But the current way is not good. Or if you have added all the buttons on scrollView you can get them all by `scrollView.subviews` by checking their class or tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

Your buttons are contained within `UIStackView`s.  There is one `verticalStackView` that contains multiple `horizontalStackView`s (each with one row of `UIButton`s).

Create an `@IBOutlet` to the `verticalStackView`, and then add your buttons to the class property called `allButtons` with the following code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var verticalStackView: UIStackView!

    var allButtons = [UIButton]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for case let horizontalStackView as UIStackView in verticalStackView.arrangedSubviews {
            for case let button as UIButton in horizontalStackView.arrangedSubviews {
                allButtons.append(button)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Original Answer:**

To create an array of all `UIButton`s with `tag == 1`:

Use *conditional cast* `as? UIButton` along with `compactMap` to find all of the buttons in `outerView.subviews` and then `filter` to select those buttons with `tag == 1`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var outerView: UIView!

    var allButtons: [UIButton] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        allButtons = outerView.subviews
                         .compactMap { $0 as? UIButton }
                         .filter { $0.tag == 1 }
    }

}
```

Note:  `outerView` is the `UIView` that contains the buttons.  Create an `@IBOutlet` to that view to make this code work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171834/discussion-on-answer-by-vacawama-swift-add-all-buttons-to-an-array).

Comment: It works! It works! It works! Thanks so much! Used the new code and now it works. Thanks so much for all your help and patience with this.
Not quite sure exactly what the for-loop does, however, but it works.
Thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome.  The outer for loop just loops through the subviews of the vertical stack view picking up one horizontal stack view each time through the loop.  The inner for loop loops through the buttons held by that horizontal stack view.  Each button is appended to the array.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

1- Make an array of buttons

```
let arrayOfButtons: [UIButton]
```

2- initialize it (give it a value)
3- then use loops to change values such as setting a button image

```
for button in arrayOfButtons {
    button.setImage(UIImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let arrayOfButtons: [UIButton]

    for i in 0....100 {
        let button  = UIButton()

        button.setImage(UIImage, forState: .normal)
        button.setTitle("test", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clickBackButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        arrayOfButtons.append(button)
    }

@IBAction func clickBackButton(_ sender: UIButton)
{
}
```

You can do with any count, i have uesd to add 100 button with title and image.

Comment: Thanks. How will it know which buttons to update?
I have around 100 buttons as mentioned, where I need to change for example the image for all of them in one go.
How will the loop know which buttons to change (for example not the one that initializes the update)?
The action for these buttons look like this (if it helps):
@IBAction func imageButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)

Comment: To solve this element of the problem, use something like `buttons.forEach { if $0 != sender { $0.setImage(image, forState: .normal } }`. This will iterate over all the buttons in the collection and update the image for all where the button does not equal the button that triggered the action.

Answer (score 0):

**1st step**: Connect all button to single IBAction in swift file

**2nd step** : Give all button a common special tag like 1010, 1007,.. etc

**3rd step**: write  code given below in your IBAction

```
@IBAction func didPressBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    for btn in self.view.subviews{
       if btn.tag == 1010
       {
                let btnRefrence = btn as! UIButton
                btnRefrence.setImage(img, for:.normal)

        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to avoid making a collection outlet, since there are so many buttons.

Comment: Sorry, I think I may not have been clear when posting this.
I have around 100 image buttons:
Then I have another button ('reset') that should change the image for all these buttons.
I believe that in the above, it would change the background color of the selected button, right?

Comment: I just tried the above.
If I use btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "image1"), for: .normal)
it says that UIView has no member 'setImage'.

Comment: No , look in Step 1 , you are connecting all button to same IBAction code so it doesn't matter which of 100 button u click it will execute on every button click and we are iterating over all subviews of self.view (and all buttons are subview of self.view) , we are detecting button from that special tag

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. However, how can I access them without having to click a button. Say I have a counter and when that reaches 30, all buttons are updated. Is this doable or is the only way forward to create an outlet collection?

Comment: `for btn in self.view.subviews{
       if btn.tag == 1010
       {
                let btnRefrence = btn as! UIButton
                btnRefrence.setImage(img, for:.normal)

        }
    }`. write this code where  u want to access all those buttons .  And don't forget to upvote

Comment: Thanks, I've inserted it as:
<code>
        for btn in self.view.subviews {
            if btn.tag == 1 {
                let btnRefrence = btn as! UIButton btnRefrence.setImage("Button1", for:.normal)
            }
        }
    }

But it gives two errors

Comment: Had to change the code, since it returned errors to:
        for btn in self.view.subviews {
            if btn.tag == 1 {
                let btnRefrence = btn as! UIButton; btnRefrence.setImage(UIImage(named: "Bubble1"), for: .normal)
            }
        }

However still no luck.
The tag for all the buttons that should be changed is '1'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171763/discussion-between-krishan-kumar-and-thomaste).

Comment: `for case let btn as UIButton in self.view.subviews where btn.tag == 1 {`